# Why isn't my program able to read the text file after the encountering the first error message?

Tags: java, file, loops, text

```
import java.util.*; // needed for scanner
import java.io.*; // needed to read text file

public class MainC
{
        public static void main(String[] args) 
        {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in); // scanner is established

        System.out.println("Welcome to the Tourist Site Simulator. In this program, we will allow you to simulate a European experience by traveling to a country in Europe"
            + "and staying there for a set number of days. "); // general explanation

        int count = 0, time = 10; // for possible repetition of instructions

 try {
        BufferedReader file = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Countries.txt"));

    while(count == 0){

        System.out.println("First of all, which of the fifty sovereign states of Europe would you like to visit?");
        String country = scan.next();

        while (file.ready()){

            String countryF = file.readLine();
            String cityF1 = file.readLine();
            String cityF2 = file.readLine();
            String cityF3 = file.readLine();
            String squiq = file.readLine();

            if(countryF.equalsIgnoreCase(country)){

            count++;
            int count2 = 0;
            while(count2 == 0){

                country = country.substring(0,1).toUpperCase() + country.substring(1);
                System.out.println("Country: " + country);
                System.out.println("");
                System.out.println("The largest cities at this nation are " + cityF1 + ", " + cityF2 + ", " +cityF3 + ". Which one would you like to visit?");
                String city = scan.next();

                if(cityF1.equalsIgnoreCase(city)||cityF2.equalsIgnoreCase(city)||cityF3.equalsIgnoreCase(city)){
                    count2++;
                    city = city.substring(0,1).toUpperCase() + city.substring(1);
                    System.out.println("");
                    System.out.println("Country: " + country);
                    System.out.println("City: " + city);

                    System.out.println("");

                    System.out.println("How many days will you be staying?");
                    int days = scan.nextInt();

                    System.out.println("");
                    System.out.println("Country: " + country + "                            Number of Days Left: " + days);
                    System.out.println("City: " + city);

                    System.out.println("");

                    System.out.println("What is the your rate of currency exchange to one Euro?");
                    double rate = scan.nextDouble();
                }else{
                    System.out.println("I must regretfully inform you that this city is not in our listed database. Please try again.");
                    System.out.println("");
                }
            }//while count == 2 
        }//while file.ready()
    }//while count == 0
        if(count == 0)
        {
        System.out.println("I must regretfully inform you that this country in not in our listed database. Please try again.");
        System.out.println("");
        }
    }

}
catch (IOException e)
{
        System.out.println(e);
}
    }
```

}

Hi there. I was having problems with this code. What it should be doing is that if the user enters an incorrect country, a loop will be initiated and the user will be asked for the country again. My problem is that after this error message comes up and the user is asked for the country again, it repeatedly asks the question regardless of whether the input is correct or not. Thank you.

Comment: Thats a very big try/catch statement. Don't try to do magic by putting your whole program into a try/catch. After your try fails and you get an error you'll carry on from the end of the catch which happens to be at the end of the program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it may be because you have your

```
if(countryF.equalsIgnoreCase(country))
```

and then from what I can see is the if statement after that is this

```
if(count == 0)
```

So your count never gets to increment if it is the wrong country.
 try this instead

```
if(countryF.equalsIgnoreCase(country){

}else(instead of if count == 0){
      "print wrong country try again"
}
```

You don't really need this either

```
while(count ==0)
```

try putting a second scan catcher in the else statement.

```
if(countryF.equalsIgnoreCase(country){

}else(instead of if count == 0){
      "print wrong country try again"
       country = scan.next();
}
```

Comment: Should that be kept outside or inside the while(file.ready()) loop?

Comment: So I think I tried what you suggested but now I have bigger problems. Now the same thing is happening and the error is being printed out multiple times.

Comment: It's working now. It looks like the main problem was the location of BufferedReader statement. Thanks.

Comment: ok Cool. Did it working taking out the while loop for count = 0?

Comment: Actually it started working when I kept the while loop for count = 0 and put the BufferedReader inside it.